# Login redirects to itself

Tags: login

Using Lubuntu, all of a sudden, when I power up and log in, I see a brief message "Dev/mc.....clean 19...../187..... files 712.../750... blocks", and am then redirected to the login screen.

I have tried holding shift during boot up but the computer booted as normal.

I have pressed escape five times during boot up and come to a "GNU GRUB" menu with the prompt "grub". Pressing TAB I see many command options but have not used any successfully.

What should I do to log in as normal again, and, what was the cause of this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For login loop.**

At login screen dont sign in press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd>. If you fall into terminal sign in and then run:

```
ls -lah | grep -i Xauthority
```

Out put should be:

```
-rw-------  1 username username   53 Apr  6 00:39 .Xauthority
```

If it is root then run:

```
sudo chown username:username .Xauthority
```

Check /tmp, run:

```
sudo ls -lah /tmp
```

If the permissions of the top one "." is drwxrwxrwt it's OK otherwise run:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

If all the above fail change your display manager to lightdm. Command:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

During the install you will be asked to choose, choose lightdm.

If the output is something like

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

When you are asked to choose, choose lightdm.

Reboot

It should work.

Comment: Thanks! It was sufficient to purge and then reinstall lightdm. But, why did this happen?

Comment: Maybe lightdm was not selected or not properly installed. Some hardwares are just not good with other display managers.